# Implementing open closed principle using generics

Tags: c#, generics, solid-principles

I'm new to using SOLID so please excuse my lack of correct terminology, correct me, if needed I am looking to learn :-)

I am in the process of upgrading a library and wanted to use the Open Closed principle, for reason of extensibility without having to modify the provider.

The library intention is to provide a list of modules based on a view type.  Based on the type the query and conditions to retrieve the modules is different.  Below is an simplied version of the current code:

```
public class ModuleProvider
{
    public List<ITreeNode> GetModules(ViewType viewType)
    {
        switch (viewType)
        {
            case ViewType.Classes
                //build query here that returns List<TreeNode> for classes
                return modules;
            case ViewType.Queries
                //build query here that returns List<TreeNode> for queries
                return modules;
        }
    }
}
```

I have read that using the switch statement for examples such as above are bad.  I understand why because if I was to add a new ViewType the GetModules will need to change.

I think I have to create an interface that has a GetModules function and then create a class for each i.e a QueryModules and ClassModules class to return then specific list.  However, I'm stuck on how will the provider above will need to change to support this?  I'm I correct in thinking I will need to use generics for this?

```
public interface IModuleProvider
{
    List<ITreeNode> GetModules();
}

public class QueryModuleProvider : IModuleProvider
{
    public List<ITreeNode> GetModules()
    {
        return new List<ITreeNode>() { new TreeNode() { Type = "Query Module" } };
    }
}

public class ClassModuleProvider : IModuleProvider
{
    public List<ITreeNode> GetModules()
    {
        return new List<ITreeNode>() {new TreeNode() { Type = "Class Module"}};
    }
}
```

Am I on the right track?  Any help the clever members of stackoverflow can give will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What do you need that isn't already covered in your second code snippet?

Comment: That approach should be fairly obvious that it's not the same - you've changed `List<ITreeNode> GetModules(ViewType viewType)` to `List<ITreeNode> GetModules()`. You're now not asking one class for the modules, but you need to decide between two classes - which is exactly the situation you started with. This is a "chicken or the egg" problem.

Comment: Look up strategy pattern. That is usually the answer to switch statements

Answer (score 0):

That approach should be fairly obvious that it's not the same - you've changed `List<ITreeNode> GetModules(ViewType viewType)` to `List<ITreeNode> GetModules()`. You're now not asking one class for the modules, but you need to decide between two classes - which is exactly the situation you started with. This is a "chicken or the egg" problem.

Instead you should inject in to your a way to dynamically decide how to build your tree nodes.

Here's an approach:

```
public class ModuleProvider
{
    private Dictionary<ViewType, Func<List<ITreeNode>>> _factory;

    public ModuleProvider(Dictionary<ViewType, Func<List<ITreeNode>>> factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    public List<ITreeNode> GetModules(ViewType viewType)
    {
        return _factory[viewType]();
    }
}
```

When you create the `ModuleProvider` you're injecting in the dictionary of factories to produce the tree nodes. You can build that dictionary in a myriad of ways without the need to recompile the assembly.